# Checking depth/z when rendering triangular faces in 3d space

Tags: java, 3d, rendering, projection, zbuffer

My question can be simplified to the following: If a 3d triangle is being projected and rendered to a 2d viewing plane, how can the z value of each pixel being rendered be calculated in order to be stored to a buffer?

I currently have a working Java program that is capable of rendering 3d triangles to the 2d view as a solid color, and the camera can be moved, rotated, etc. with no problem, working exactly how one would expect it to, but if I try to render two triangles over each other, the one closer to the camera being expected to obscure the farther one, this isn't always the case. A Z buffer seems like the best idea as to how to remedy this issue, storing the z value of each pixel I render to the screen, and then if there's another pixel trying to be rendered to the same coordinate, I compare it to the z value of the current pixel when deciding which one to render. The issue I'm now facing is as follows:

How do I determine the z value of each pixel I render? I've thought about it, and there seem to be a few possibilities. One option involves finding the equation of the plane(ax + by + cz + d = 0) on which the face lies, then some sort of interpolation of each pixel in the triangle being rendered(e.g. halfway x-wise on the 2d rendered triangle -> halfway x-wise through the 3d triangle, same for the y, then solve for z using the plane's equation), though I'm not certain this would work. The other option I thought of is iterating through each point, with a given quantum, of the 3d triangle, then render each point individually, using the z of that point(which I'd also probably have to find through the plane's equation).

Again, I'm currently mainly considering using interpolation, so the pseudo-code would look like(if I have the plane's equation as "ax + by + cz + d = 0"):

```
xrange = (pixel.x - 2dtriangle.minX)/(2dtriangle.maxX - 2dtriangle.minX)
yrange = (pixel.y - 2dtriangle.minY)/(2dtriangle.maxY - 2dtriangle.minY)
x3d = (3dtriangle.maxX - 3dtriangle.minX) * xrange + 3dtriangle.minX
y3d = (3dtriangle.maxY - 3dtriangle.minY) * yrange + 3dtriangel.minY
z = (-d - a*x3d - b*y3d)/c
```

Where `pixel.x` is the x value of the pixel being rendered, `2dtraingle.minX` and `2dtriangle.maxX` are the minimum and maximum x values of the triangle being rendered(i.e. of its bounding box) **after having been projected onto the 2d view**, and it's min/max Y variables are the same, but for its Y. `3dtriangle.minX` and `3dtriangle.maxX` are the minimum and maximum x values of the 3d triangle **before having been projected onto the 2d view**, `a, b, c, and d` are the coefficients of the equation of the plane on which the 3d triangle lies, and `z` is the corresponding z value of the pixel being rendered.

Will that method work? If there's any ambiguity **please let me know in the comments before closing the question**! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be calculating the depth for each vertex of the triangle. Then we are able to get the depth of each pixel the same way we do for the colors when rendering a triangle with Gouraud shading. Doing that simultaneously with rendering allows to check the depth easily.

If we have a situation like this:

[image: triangle]

And we start to draw lines from the top to the bottom. We calculate the slopes from the point one to the others, and add the correct amount of depth every time we move to the next line... And so on.

You did't provide your rendering method, so can't say anything specific to it, but you should take a look at some tutorials related to Gouraud shading. Do some simple modifications to them and you should be able to use it with depth values.

Well, hopefully this helps!

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but I just have on question. Do I calculate the slopes of dy/dx on the lines of the 2d rendered triangle, or do I calculate the slopes of the edges of the 3d triangle before it's projected?

Comment: @user2649681 Based on the 2D triangles. After you have calculated the vertices from the point of the view, you don't need the original space coordinates anymore.